# Context root automatically changing to temp folder name in JBOSS EAP 6.4

Tags: jboss, wildfly, seam, jboss6.x

I have an application that I am trying to deploy to JBoss EAP 6.4. I don't see any errors while deploying the application. However, when I try to access the application with the context root like `http://localhost:8080/contextroot/` I am being redirected to `http://localhost:8080/contextroot.war-345rdser34dwwe/login.jsp` where `contextroot.war-345rdser34dwwe` is a folder created under `${jboss.home}/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp`

This is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>   <!-- Make sub deployments isolated by default, so they cannot see each others 
    classes without a Class-Path entry -->
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>   <!-- This corresponds to the top level deployment. For a war this is the 
    war's module, for an ear -->  <!-- This is the top level ear module, which contains all the classes in 
    the EAR's lib folder -->
<deployment>
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar"  use-physical-code-source="true"/>
    </resources>
      <!-- exclude-subsystem prevents a subsystems deployment unit processors running 
        on a deployment -->     <!-- which gives basically the same effect as removing the subsystem, but 
        it only affects single deployment -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.javassist" />
        <module name="org.hibernate" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
        <module name="org.jboss.msc" />
        <module name="javax.faces.api" />
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider" />
    </exclusions>
         <!-- This allows you to define additional dependencies, it is the same as 
        using the Dependencies: manifest attribute -->
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.company.app.config" optional="TRUE"/>         
        <module name="deployment.module.nested.app"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
<module name="deployment.module.nested.app">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="../contextroot.war"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

This is my `jboss-web.xml`

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
"-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 4.2//EN"
"http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_2.dtd">

<jboss-web>  
    <security-domain>UserModule</security-domain>
    <security-domain>ServiceModule</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

This is my config in standalone-ha.xml for security subsystem

```
    <security-domain name="UserModule" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.company.uas.service.authentication.loginmodule.UserLoginModule" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="ServiceModule" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.company.uas.service.authentication.loginmodule.ServiceLoginModule" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
    </security-domain>
```

I have been working on it for couple of days now but could not find anything online related to this issue.

Comment: Wouldn't it help setting the context root in jboss-web.xml?

    <jboss-web>
        <context-root>/context-root</context-root>
    </jboss-web>

Comment: @jpangamarca I tried that but still I face the same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure if I consider this an answer but I understood why my `/contextroot` was changing to /`contextroot.war-345rdser34dwwe`. This was because, I was deploying a war file to JBoss and JBoss was pointing to the exploded version of my war file which was present in the `tmp` folder for some reason.

I deployed an exploded version of my war file with the name `contextroot.war` as the name of the folder and it worked.